# Why is my call to sys.argv not being recognized?

Tags: python, udp, client, ping

I'm trying to implement the client side of a UDP pinger program. I am currently receiving this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../UDPClient.py", line 5, in <module>
    host = argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here is the sample solution code:

```
import sys, time
from socket import *

argv = sys.argv
host = argv[1]
port = argv[2]
timeout = 1  # in second

clientsocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
clientsocket.settimeout(timeout)
port = int(port)
ptime = 0

while ptime < 10:
    ptime += 1
    data = "Ping " + str(ptime) + " " + time.asctime()

try:
    RTTb = time.time()
    clientsocket.sendto(data, (host, port))
    message, address = clientsocket.recvfrom(1024)
    RTTa = time.time()
    print "Reply from " + address[0] + ": " + message
    print "RTT: " + str(RTTa - RTTb)
except:
    print "Request timed out."
    continue

clientsocket.close()
```

Any ideas on what is happening? I don't understand why this wouldn't work.

Comment: It seems you need to pass two arguments and you may be passing none. It looks like you have to do something like this .../UDPClient.py 10.10.10.10 80

Comment: I'm not sure how to pass in arguments. I'm extremely new to this, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention how you're invoking the program, but I'm guessing it's something like `py UDPClient.py` rather than something like `py UDPClient.py foo bar`. The program name, `UDPClient.py`, is the 0th element in `sys.argv`. The first argument you add is the 1st element, and so on.